# Excel 2007 Ribbon splitbutton with submenu

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I've got a simple split button in my Ribbon. And under it I have two buttons in the menu.
It works well.
Now I want to extend the first button -button id="rxBtn_CreateDataFiles" - into more options,
and have another submenu extend to the right with two more choices.

What would be the syntax for it? Thanks.

```
<splitButton id="rxspb_CreateDataFiles" size="normal">
    <button id="rxBtn_CreateDataFilesFace" label="Data Files" imageMso="ChartEditDataSource"/>
    <menu id="rxmnuCreateDataFiles">
        <button id="rxBtn_CreateDataFiles" label="Run EQ" onAction="QRCreateDataFiles_Click" imageMso="ExportExcel"/>
        <button id="rxBtn_CreateSpecificDataFiles" label="Run Select EQ" onAction="QRCreateDataFilesForSpecific_Click" imageMso="ExportExcel"/>

    </menu>
</splitButton >
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Just need to insert another menu section in the middle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do: Create the buttons in VBA using Ribbon Commander and then export XML to a static Ribbon using .serializeToXML

With rxCustomUI.defaultInstance

```
    With .ribbon.tabs.Add(New rxTab)
        .Label = "tab"
```